# $95$ percent confidence interval for roll of two dice

Tags: probability, dice

Given a roll of two fair six-sided dice, we know the expectation for a specific result (e.g. a $4$ and another $4$) is $\frac{1}{36}$.

But with what certainty could you expect that result in $N$ throws of the dice?  I recall that it is certainly not "$100$% for $N=36$ throws" but I cannot recall how to calculate, for example, the value of $N$ such that I have a $95$% certainty that my specific result would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are $36$ results and $\frac 1{36}=2\frac 79\%$, you can only afford to miss one-two puts you over $5\%$.  So your $95\%$ confidence interval for the sum of the dice can be $[2,11]$ or $[3,12]$.  Take your pick.